# Need help creating a PowerShell scirpt to clear Active Directory attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am brand new to PowerShell and looking to create a script that clears the following attributes/fields by user not OU from the general, address, telephones, and organization tabs.

1. General Tab - Description, Office, Telephone number
2. Address tab -  Street, P.O. Box, City, State/province, Zip/Postal Code
3. Telephones Tab -  Home, Pager, Mobile, Fax, IP phone
4. Organization Tab - Job Title, Department, Company, Manager

I am currently performing this process via the GUI (AD Users and Computers) and thought it would improve efficiency.

This is as far as I got:

```
$user = Read-Host "Enter user name"
Set-ADUser $user
```

Thank you,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$user = Read-Host "Enter User name"
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADUser -Clear Attributes single quoted separated by comma IE 'Description','Office' etc
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up coming up with:set-aduser username -Clear company, department, ipphone, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, company, title, facsimileTelephoneNumber, pager, telephonenumber, manager, description, homephone, mobile, l, st
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity username | Remove-adgroupmember -member username -confirm:$false